# spring mvc rest mongo dbobject response

Tags: json, spring, rest, mongodb

i want to create a spring mvc rest call and the response should be the results from the mongo db (Basic)DBObject. the DBObject is, as far as i know, a JSON object. is it possible to return this objects or should i return the normal string content of them?

this is the solution i have so far:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/content/json/{ids}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getContentByIdsAsJSON(@PathVariable("ids") String ids)
{
  String content = null;
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");

  List<String> list = this.contentService.findContentByListingIdAsJSON(ids);
  if (list.isEmpty())
  {
     content = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><error>no data found</error>";
     return new ResponseEntity<String>(content, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
  for (String json : list)
  {
     builder.append(json + "\n");
  }
  content = builder.toString();
  return new ResponseEntity<String>(content, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

does anyone have a better solution for that requirement?

thx very much in advance.
simon

Comment: does nobody have a clue for my kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm see a strange thing in you code. Do you must return json or xml? If you must return json it's simple in your situation, @ResponseBody do the magic

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/content/json/{ids}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public MyGreatContentObject getContentByIdsAsJSON(@PathVariable("ids") String ids) {
   return this.contentService.findContentByListingId(ids);
}
```

in any way, i'm think you still must learn base concepts a little more