# spring mvc rest response json and xml

Tags: xml, json, spring, rest, mongodb

I have the requirement to return the result from the database either as a string in xml-structure or as json-structure.
I've got a solution, but I don't know, if this one is the best way to solve this.
I have two methods here:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/content/json/{ids}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getContentByIdsAsJSON(@PathVariable("ids") String ids)
{
  String content = null;
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
  // responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

  List<String> list = this.contentService.findContentByListingIdAsJSON(ids);
  if (list.isEmpty())
  {
     content = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><error>no data  found</error>";
     return new ResponseEntity<String>(content, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
  for (String json : list)
  {
     builder.append(json + "\n");
  }
  content = builder.toString();
  return new ResponseEntity<String>(content, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/content/{ids}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getContentByIdsAsXML(@PathVariable("ids") String ids)
{
  HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8");

  String content = this.contentService.findContentByListingIdAsXML(ids);
  if (content == null)
  {
     content = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><error>no data found</error>";
     return new ResponseEntity<String>(content, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
  return new ResponseEntity<String>(content, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

for the first method I need a better solution, which I already asked here: 
[spring mvc rest mongo dbobject response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466063/spring-mvc-rest-mongo-dbobject-response)

The next thing is, that I inserted in the configuration a json converter:

```
<bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
   <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
</bean>
```

when I change the content-type at the first method to "application/json", it works, but then the xml response doesn't work anymore, because the json converter wants to convert the xml string to json-structure I think.

what can I do, that spring identifies the difference that the one method should return a json type and the other one a normal xml as string?
I tried it with the accept flag:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/content/json/{ids}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
```

but this doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

I hope that somebody can help me out.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using Spring 3.1, you can take advantage of the new `produces` element on the `@RequestMapping` annotation to ensure that you produce XML or JSON as you wish, even within the same app.

I wrote a post about this here:

http://springinpractice.com/2012/02/22/supporting-xml-and-json-web-service-endpoints-in-spring-3-1-using-responsebody/

Comment: This is a great answer, which takes into account serving xml and json effectively. It's not as simple as Jersey's Jaxson implementation, but I'll take it.

Answer (score 8):

Whoa...when you're working with Spring, assume someone else has come up against the same issue.  You can dump all the server-side JSON generation, because all you need to do is:

1. Include the Jackson JSON JARs in your app
2. Set the `RequestMapping` return type to `@ResponseBody(yourObjectType)`

Spring will auto-magically convert your object to JSON.  Really.  Works like magic.

Doc for `@ResponseBody`: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody

Comment: If you have the return type for the method set to `@ResponseBody MyObject` and have the Jackson JARs on your classpath, Spring does the conversion.  Are you using Spring 3?

Comment: thanks for the info on ResponseBody... i have to add something, though: @RequestMapping(value = "/pets/{petId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Pet getPet(@PathVariable String petId, Model model) {
    // implementation omitted
}

Answer (score 4):

You can use ContentNegotiatingViewResolver as below:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <ref bean="xmlView"/>
            <ref bean="jsonView"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonView"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
    <property name="contentType" value="application/json;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <property name="disableCaching" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="xmlView"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
    <property name="contentType" value="application/xml;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="xstreamMarshaller"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>


<bean id="xstreamMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
    <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true" />
    <property name="annotatedClass" value="demo.domain.xml.XMLResponse"/>
    <property name="supportedClasses" value="demo.domain.xml.XMLResponse"/>
</bean>
```

In your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get/response.json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public JSONResponse getJsonResponse(){
    return responseService.getJsonResponse();
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/get/response.xml", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public  XMLResponse getXmlResponse(){
    return responseService.getXmlResponse();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone using Spring Boot for XML response then add the following dependency,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And in the model class you are returning add the `@XmlRootElement`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {
      //... fields and getters, setters
}
```

and in your controller add `produces="application/xml"`. This will produce the response in xml format.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot research i think i have a good solution for this: very simple, spring by default, uses Jackson to working with Json, that library comes in the ***spring-boot-starter-web***, but the Xml extention of Jackson doesn't come by default, all you need to do is import in your build.gradle or in your pom.xml the ***jackson-dataformat-xml*** dependency and now you can alternate between json or xml for example with a code like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/personjson")
public ResponseEntity<?> getJsonPerson (@RequestBody Person person) {
    return ResponseEntity.accepted().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .body(person);
}

@PostMapping(value = "/personxml")
public ResponseEntity<?> getXmlPerson (@RequestBody Person person) {
    return ResponseEntity.accepted().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .body(person);
}
```

Where person is a bean (only have the @Component tag), Lock at that both codes are equal only the MediaType is different and it works!!, ***isn't nesesary too add the "produces" and "consumes"*** atributes to the Mapping tag, because Spring, by default, can consume both Json and Xml, i did an example sending a Json and getting. xml, and sending xml getting a Json, ***only you need to specify in your postman or in curl when you do the request, the correct header of the body that you are sending either application/json or application/xml.***

Note: this is only a way a todo this, JAXB and XmlRootElement, is other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here I wrote method which take XML as request parameter from your request mapping URL

Here I am posting XML to my URL "baseurl/user/createuser/"

```
    public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "createuser/" ,
    method=RequestMethod.POST,  consumes= "application/xml")
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<String> createUser(@RequestBody String requestBody ) {

        String r = "<ID>10</ID>"; // Put whatever response u want to return to requester

    return new ResponseEntity<String>(
              "Handled application/xml request. Request body was: " 
              + r, 
              new HttpHeaders(), 
              HttpStatus.OK);       


    }
}
```

I tested it using chrome poster where you can send any xml in  content body like:

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <userEntity><id>3</id><firstName>saurabh</firstName><lastName>shri</lastName><password>pass</password><userName>test@test.com</userName></userEntity>"
```

This XML will capture by my createUser method and stored in String requestBody which i can use further

Comment: is there a way to remove `standalone="yes"` when I do have a xmlns?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this to get JSON response would be:
Using Spring 3.1, you could do as follows

1. In your pom.xml file (hoping you are using a maven project), add maven dependency for jackson-mapper (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13)
2. Modify your code as follows and test the endpoint on postman:

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/content/json/{ids}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public @ResponseBody String getContentByIdsAsJSON(@PathVariable("ids") String ids){
       String content = "";
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

       List<String> list = this.contentService.findContentByListingIdAsJSON(ids);
       if (list.isEmpty()){
           content = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><error>no data found</error>";
           return content;
       }
       for (String json : list){
           builder.append(json + "\n");
       }

       content = builder.toString();
       return content;
   }
   ```