# Return JSON data type/view from Spring controller

Tags: java, json, web-services, spring

How do I convert an existing XML-based web service to JSON-type web service?

I have this sample resource:

```
@Controller
public class CustomerController {
    @RequestMapping(value="customers", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody CustomerList customers(Model model) {
        CustomerList list = new CustomerList();
        list.getCustomer().add(new Customer("1", "John Doe"));
        list.getCustomer().add(new Customer("2", "Jane Doe"));
        return list;
    }
}
```

So far, I am not experiencing any error with regards to accessing it, I just want to change the data that this service return to the client from XML to JSON.

With this entity:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "customer"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "CustomerList")
public class CustomerList {

    @XmlElement(name = "Customer", required = true)
    protected List<Customer> customer;

    public List<Customer> getCustomer() {
        if (customer == null) {
            customer = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        }
        return this.customer;
    }

}
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="com.mycompany.api.model"/>
<beans:bean id="customerList" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="marshaller"/>
</beans:bean>
```

How can I change the output of the service to JSON? Do I need to put JSON-type annotations in the entity/model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Jackson JSON processor](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), your code would remarkably similar. The model will be in simple POJO format. Use @ResponseBody for your response again and Jackson will take care of the JSON conversion.

See this [Spring 3 MVC and JSON example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/).

Comment: From what I see, the only difference in the code I provided from the sample codes from the link you provided is the fact that I used the XML Marshalling view. Removing that tag I get this error: WARNING: /customers
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.xml.bind.JAXBPermission" "setDatatypeConverter")

Comment: If you have a dual response type then you could use ContentNegotiatingViewResolver e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467119/spring-mvc-rest-response-json-and-xml

Comment: Right, I fixed the problem by removing the Jaxb annotation in my entity/models. Dual response may be a good option too.