# How to serve dynamically generated files from a spring-mvc webapp

Tags: spring-mvc, web-applications, client-server

I am developing a webapp using the Spring-MVC framework.

My webapp, on a client request, must dynamically generate an xml file and serve it. A javascript at the client side can then use this to do stuff.

I tried generating the xml files in my webapps resources directory and serving them. This obviously didn't work as the resources directory is packaged into the war when the webapp is deployed.

How do I go about doing this? I suspect that I am missing something at a conceptual level here than anything spring-mvc specific.

I am new to this kind of thing though I know how to serve normal static files and even template files(like jsp's) which are filled with data dynamically.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467119/spring-mvc-rest-response-json-and-xml). Basically you need a RESTful service

Comment: What are you generating your XML files from? Are they serialised java objects of some kind?

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond, Thanks. ResponseEntity was exactly what I needed. If you can put this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Richard, No. They are not a serialized java objects. I need to render graphs in my view. They are a representation of graphs.

Comment: I think your question is a bit large. But just to give you a pointer. Spring MVC usually relies on you handing a java object (the model) to the 'view' renderer. The view renderer then automatically converts the java object into XML or JSON or whatever. You need to get your graph data into a java object, and then just set up the correct MVC view (investigate ContentNegotiatingViewHandler) etc.

Comment: Or you could write the XML into the response yourself inside the MVC controller. Set the correct mimetype in the response header, get the response printwriter, and write it. Then just return null from the controller.

Comment: @Abhijithaexp - Glad I could be of help. :) Apparently it would be unnecessary to put it as answer because we already have the info available as answers in shared post. Since you find them useful do upvote them!